# Exercise - Student t distribution / Normal distribution - determine the proportion of samples exceeding some value

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, sampling

Is my reasoning on the following exercise correct? I am not sure if I correctly used Student t distribution instead of normal distribution and whether my calculation of std makes sense.

*Exercise*:
"Four samples are taken and averaged every hour from a production line and the hourly measurement of a particular impurity is recorded. Approximately one out of six of these averages exceeds 1.5% when the mean value is approximately 1.4%. State assumptions that would enable you to determine the proportion of the individual readings exceeding 1.6%. Make the assumptions and do the calculations. Are these assumptions likely to be true? If not, how might they be violated?"

*My attempted solution:*

$n=4$, $df=3$ 
$\mu = 1.4\%$ 
$P(x>1.5\%) = 1/6$ 
$P(x>1.6\%) = ?$

Since the sample size is small and we don't know the population std, we need to use the Student-t distribution (with 3 degrees of freedom). For that, we need to assume that the samples are IID.
To compute the t-score we need $\sigma$, which is not given, but we can compute it from the information that $P(x>1.5\%) = 1/6 \approx 0.167$. It means that we can compute the value of t-statistic with inverse cdf of $1-0.167=0.833$. Inverse cdf for t-distribution with 3 degrees of freedom for $0.833$ is approximately $1.15$. From that we know:
$$1.15 = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1.5\%-1.4\%}{\sigma/\sqrt{4}} = \frac{0.1\%}{\sigma/2}$$
hence $\sigma = 0.174\%$. 
Now we can compute the t-score for $1.6\%$ which is:
$$t = \frac{1.6\%-1.4\%}{0.174\%/2} \approx 2.3$$
Next, reading from t-tables, we can check the value of $P(x>1.6\%)=P(t>2.3) \approx 0.05$, so there is around $5\%$ chance of getting a reading greater than $1.6\%$.

The assumption of IID could be not true if the samples were taken from different sources, or if the samples were not independent.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming that

> 1. Each measurement follows the normal distribution $N(1.4,\sigma^2)$ (reasonable assumption for many measurements)
> 2. The measurements are iid (as they are randomly sampled from the same line randomly at a certain time),
> 3. The process is in control (the mean and variance remain unchanged).

we have that the hourly average $\bar{X} \sim N(1.4,\frac{\sigma^2}{4})$. Then, from

$$P(\bar{X}>1.5\%) = P \left (Z=\frac{\bar{X}-1.4}{\sigma/\sqrt{4}}>\frac{1.5-1.4}{\sigma/\sqrt{4}} \right)  =1-\Phi\left (\frac{1.5-1.4}{\sigma/\sqrt{4}} \right)=1/6,$$

you can obtain $\sigma^2$, and then you can compute

$$P(\bar{X}>1.6\%).$$

Working with T distribution is not needed here as we can directly compute $\sigma^2$.

If the sample is taken fully randomly at a certain time, in practice, only the first assumption may be violated, and $\bar{X}$ may not follow $N(1.4,\frac{\sigma^2}{4})$ as the sample size is only $4$. For a larger sample size ($\ge 30$), we can use the CLT. Note that for some population distributions (such as uniform distribution) even for $n=4$, the distribution of $\bar{X}$ becomes very similar to a normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so if I understood correctly - we don't have to use Student T distribution, even though the sample is small because: 
1. we have the population $\sigma$ 
2. since we assume that the population distribution is normal then the $\bar X$ will be also normal even for small sample like 4. Is that correct?

Comment: @SlimakSlimak Yes, the sample mean has a normal distribution for any sample size  when the population distribution follows a normal distribution:

$$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim N(0,1).$$

See the second part of this page: https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_introductory-statistics/s10-02-the-sampling-distribution-of-t.html

----

When $\sigma^2$ is unknown (which is not the case here), the following statistic with *T distribution*: 

$$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim T_{n-1},$$ 

is used for constructing confidence intervals and statistical tests.